# How to get dynamic property names?

Tags: coldfusion

I've got array of key names and a structure containing the data.
I need to loop through the structure and print out all the property values, based on the key-array.
my key value contains for example values

```
propList array contains:
id, name, haircolor, age
```

I want to go through the structure and print out values for

```
item.id
item.name
item.haircolor
item.age
(or any properties stored in the array)
```

I've tried to print out

```
<cfoutput>"#item.propName#"</cfoutput>
```

where propName is retrieved from looping through **propList** array.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have an array of structures or something? if you only have one level of properties in the structure you don't  need the two loops? You just have to do:

```
<cfloop array="#myStructures#" item="item">
    <cfloop array="#propList#" index="key">
        <cfoutput>#item[key]#</cfoutput>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

Or to be safer:

```
<cfloop array="#myStructures#" item="item">
    <cfloop array="propList" index="key">
        <cfif StructKeyExists(item, key)>
        <cfoutput>#item[key]#</cfoutput>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: yep, it is array containing structures.

Comment: I have updated the code now that you clarified you have an array of structures.

Answer (score 2):

You can use array notation to get values form a structure when the key is 'dynamic'.

```
<cfloop index="item" array=#input#>
    <cfloop list="#rawColumnList#" delimiters="," index="value">
        <cfoutput>#item[ value ]#</cfoutput>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: ... unfortunately I am getting diagnostics:Invalid CFML construct found on line...

Comment: This is the right general idea.  You should be able to work out the details.

Answer (score -4):

a solution:

```
<cfloop index="item" array=#input#>
    <cfloop list="#rawColumnList#" delimiters="," index="value">
        <cfset output=Evaluate("item.#value#")>
        <cfoutput>#output#</cfoutput>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: While `evaluate()` is much more efficient than it used to be, you don't need to use `evaluate()` for this. Simply use array notation.